# How to move svg image using selenium element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver, selenium3

This is HTML code before having the element in svg.

[image]

After that, I pull a new element from the sidebar into svg and HTML code like that
[image]

So I want to move a new element to new position in svg.
Example: Element have a position is (328,201) and I want to move to new position is (0,0) in svg.
I have tried another way to move the element in svg but not work. Anyone have an idea to perform

```
WebElement From = driver.findElement(itemListSVG);

act.moveToElement(From, 0, 0).build().perform();


act.click(From).moveToElement(From, 0, 0).build().perform();
```

Comment: Is it movable manually?

Comment: Yes, I can move element manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works :D

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(element)).build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(svgGridElement,50,50).build().perform();
builder.release().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing actually is:

1. Click an item (`click`)
2. Moving a mouse pointer to that item (`moveToElement` which accepts the **target** element as its parameter)

There are no actions defined for dragging and dropping the items whatever they are (svg or other types of elements). You should use one of the following approaches:

1. `dragAndDropBy(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset)` where you set **what** you drag and drop and the offset to **where** you drag and drop
2. Use `clickAndHold(WebElement onElement)` that would emulate holding your element with a mouse, then `moveByOffset(int xOffset, int yOffset)` or `moveToElement(WebElement toElement)` and then `release()` that would release your mouse button.

Comment: I have following with 1 but not work: `WebElement From = driver.findElement(itemRecipientListSVG);
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(From).moveByOffset(608, 181).release().build().perform();`

Comment: @SinhVienIT what are these coordinates `608, 181`?

Comment: This position I get from svg by manual

Comment: And I have to try Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.dragAndDropBy(From, 608, 181).release().build().perform(); and I get error org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @SinhVienIT these should be the target position offset. That means that if your source svg element has the position say `{x=600, y=100}`, and target place you'd like to move it to `{x=608, y=181}`, then your offsets would be `{xOffset=8, yOffset=81}`. Check that you use the method properly.

Comment: I have tried this {xOffset=8, yOffset=81} but the element I want to move still stay in position

Comment: @SinhVienIT the above was just an example. You should check what exact position your source element has, what exact position would be your target and evaluate the offset correspondingly.

Comment: Yes, It's about how to get a new position in svg include xoffset, yoffset like you said. Do you think about this? WebElement From = driver.findElement(itemRecipientListSVG);

        Point point = From.getLocation();
        int xOffset = point.getX();
        int yOffset = point.getX();
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.clickAndHold(From).moveByOffset(xOffset+1, yOffset+1).release().build().perform(); I have tried but not work too.

Comment: @SinhVienIT the latter code should move your element to one pixel right and down. This might be not working due several reasons. Is what you are testing publicly available? I would take a look then.

Comment: No, It's not public :(. Do you know how to get target position in svg ? I don't have solution to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding move to element before the click and hold.

```
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.MoveToElement(element);
        action.ClickAndHold().MoveByOffset(offsetX, offsetY).Release();
        action.Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood when you are trying to move the element you are getting StaleElementReferenceException. 
Are you handling that?
If no try doing following
1. Use explicit wait
2. Use try catch around the code. If it worked let me know else go for another solution.
and use dragAndDropBy(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset) rather that clickAndHold().moveByOffset(x-offset, y-offset).release()
To get actual offset manually you can use browser ruler.